# When to make widget a variable according to tkinter coding standards?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, coding-style, standards

If I were to make a button or label that won't be called or re-configed anywhere else in the code should I make it a variable or just create that instance? Just instantiating it makes it more readable IMO and uses less memory (not that I have to think about it using python), but I see most people creating a instance variable. Which one is the "better" way of writing it (assuming I don't need to call it later)?

```
Button(root, text="Button").grid(row=0, column=0)
```

or

```
self.my_button = Button(root, text="Button")
self.my_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Comment: If you don't need to *access* (the term "call" is incorrect) the widget later, there is usually no reason to assign the instance created to a variable. There really isn't a "tkinter coding standard" for this. I often assign them to variables for consistency and just in case I need to access them later.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I always assign widgets to variables. They aren't always instance variables; sometimes they are local variables. I'll use instance or global variables if I ever need to reference the widget outside of the function where it is defined.

In my opinion, tkinter code is much easier to understand when widgets are created and laid out in separate blocks and grouped together logically. When all of the layout code is in a block it's much easier to visualize the layout.

In other words, instead of this:

```
root = Tk()
Canvas(root, ...).grid(...)
toolbar = Frame(root,...).grid(...)
Label(toolbar,...).pack(...)
Button(toolbar, ...).pack(...)
```

... I prefer this:

```
toolbar = Frame(root, ...)
canvas = Canvas(root, ...)
app_icon = Label(toolbar,...)
save_button = Button(toolbar, ...)

toolbar.grid(...)
canvas.grid(...)

app_icon.pack(...)
save_button.pack(...)
```

I think it becomes much more clear that the toolbar and canvas are laid out together in the window, and that the label and icon are part of the toolbar.

Comment: The question was not about whether to include geometry on the same line or separately,  
 or the layout, I believe they were asking if it's standard to assign widgets to variables, or just declare them without assigning them. The answer was partially on track.

Comment: @Jayce: I gave my opinion which is to always associate widgets with variables, and then backed that opinion up with my reasoning and examples.